# How to Completely Disable Yellow Warning Lines in VS Code for Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

---

**Question**:

I'm working on a Python project in Visual Studio Code, and I'm getting persistent yellow warning lines in my code. I want to completely disable these, but so far, I've had no luck. Here's what I've tried:
[image]

1. **Disabling Pylint and Other Linters**: I've attempted to disable all Python linting by adding the following to my `settings.json` file:

   ```json
   "python.linting.enabled": false
   ```
2. **Changing the Type Checking Mode**: I've modified the Python analysis settings in my `settings.json` file as follows:

   ```json
   "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic"
   "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "off"
   ```
3. **Customizing Editor Warnings and Errors**: I've tried to change the color of the error and warning lines with the following settings in my `settings.json` file:

   ```json
   "editorError.foreground": "#00000000",
   "editorWarning.foreground": "#00000000",
   "editorInfo.foreground": "#00000000"
   ```
4. **Restarting VS Code**: I've fully closed and reopened VS Code after making these changes.
5. **Checking Workspace and Project-Specific Settings**: I've checked for workspace or project-specific settings that might be overriding my global settings.

Despite these attempts, the yellow warning lines have not disappeared. They changed from red to yellow, but I would like to remove them entirely. How can I achieve this?

---

Comment: Please post the code as text too.

Comment: I don't really use VS Code, but can't you just hide and unhide different types of errors in the 'Problems' section? Atleast that's possible in normal Visual Studio.

Comment: @AndreasSabelfeld nope, VSC is completely different thing from Microsoft's VS.

Comment: What warnings do they prompt? Hover the mouse over the squiggly line or show the **PROBLEM** panel.

Comment: @Daviid, ok ,it is modified now

Comment: @JialeDu, I'm encountering a warning that says "Undefined 'AverageMeter' Pylance reportUndefinedVariable (function) AverageMete. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: @郑远程 I meant the code in the image, and the whole code if possible, I can see in the minimap that there's yellow in the top of the code, probably the imports which could mean pylance doesn't find the packages you imported, hence the problem.

Comment: @Daviid, the yellow in the top of the code, is the code that is shown in the image. There are no imports shown on the minimap. It does seem like the top of the minimap is cut off though

Comment: @Daviid, I'm actually just trying to study a specific segment of deep learning code by placing it in a new file. Therefore, errors and warnings are to be expected. What I really want is for the editor to ignore these and not display them. I'm not looking to resolve the errors but merely to study the code without the distraction of these warnings. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @郑远程 I wrote an answer, does it help?

Comment: @JialeDu extremely good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not looking to resolve the errors but merely to study the code without the distraction of these warnings.

> I understand that warnings generally indicate potential issues in the code, but in this specific case, I'm working with a segment of code for learning purposes, and the warnings were more of a distraction.

For this there is the following method

##### Violent solution:

```
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
        "reportUndefinedVariable": "none"
    },
```

*But warnings generally indicate that your code may be incorrect, and the most correct way should be to modify your code to be correct and compliant.*

More configurable values for this setting can be found in **Diagnostic severity rules** in this link.

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_python-language-server-settings*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I understand that warnings generally indicate potential issues in the code, but in this specific case, I'm working with a segment of code for learning purposes, and the warnings were more of a distraction. Your suggestion works perfectly for what I need. Thanks again!

Comment: I added more information, hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: ,so kind of you,thank u!!